# Weird colors on Chrome on Ubuntu 20.04 after latest update

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, colors

There used to be a setting in `chrome://flags/` to `Force color profile` to `sRGB`, but since the latest update this morning to Version `84.0.4147.89`, there's no such setting.

Is anyone else having the same issue? And anyone knows any other fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm having the same issue. As far as I found, changing the desktop shortcut adding `--force-color-profile=srgb` works. Like this:

```
google-chrome-stable --force-color-profile=srgb
```

Answer (score 1):

I've realized this is a problem with Chromium & Electron based applications picking the wrong color profile. While the solution mentioned here solves the problem for Chrome, the solution I've found fixes it for all Chromium/Electron based applications, such as VSCode & Discord.

The solution is in [this Google Docs document](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1jMokB_OBkZVELu22li8vnHxAUoL1eGnLedP-1Gttv40/edit#heading=h.z8rbug83238e) - we need to follow the 5 steps under "Using colormgr from the command line". This fixed the issue on all Chromium-based applications by setting sRGB as the default color profile.

> #### Step 1: Get the object path for the sRGB colorspace.
>
> Do this by running:
>
> ```
> colormgr get-standard-space srgb
> ```
>
> Note down the “Object Path” (it will be something like /org/freedesktop/…). We’ll refer to this path as SRGB_PATH in future steps.
>
> #### Step 2: Get the object paths for the devices for which you want to reset.
>
> Do this by running
>
> ```
> colormgr get-devices
> ```
>
> Note down the “Object Path” of each device you want to set the color profile for (again it will be something like /org/freedesktop/…). We’ll refer to each of these paths as DISPLAY_PATH in future steps.
>
> #### Step 3: For each device, register the sRGB color profile with the device.
>
> Do this by running:
>
> ```
> colormgr device-add-profile DISPLAY_PATH SRGB_PATH
> ```
>
> Where SRGB_PATH is the path obtained in step 1 and DISPLAY_PATH is the path for each device obtained in step 2. Note that you may ignore error reports saying “profile object path … has already been added”.
>
> #### Step 4: For each device, set the default color profile to be the sRGB color profile.
>
> Do this by running:
>
> ```
> colormgr device-make-profile-default DISPLAY_PATH SRGB_PATH
> ```
>
> Again, Where SRGB_PATH is the path obtained in step 1 and DISPLAY_PATH is the path for each device obtained in step 2.
>
> #### Step 5: Restart Chrome
>
> Using `xprop` (current session only)
> To remove the color profile for the current session only, run
>
> ```
> xprop -root -remove _ICC_PROFILE
> ```
>
> You’ll need to restart Chrome for us to re-read the property.
>
> Note that this will only apply to the current session.

Comment: It worked very well on Ubuntu 22.04 and Chrome Version 101.0.4951.54 (Official Build) unknown (64-bit)